# Where can I obtain dictionary files for use in checking spelling?

Tags: dictionary

I thought this was asked before, but 15 minutes of searching on Google and the site search didn't turn anything up...so:

Where can I obtain free (as in beer and/or as in speech) dictionary files? I'm mainly interested in English, but if you know of any dictionary files, please point them out.

Note: This question doesn't have a right/wrong answer, so I made it community-wiki. However, I feel that it might be valuable to not only myself, but anyone who wishes to implement or use a spell checker with various dictionary files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a [SourceForge project called Word List](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/), which appears to have a number of dictionaries. I have downloaded a couple and am currently checking them out.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can look in places like `/usr/share/dict/words`

Answer (score 1):

I would presume that OpenOffice contains dictionaries for several languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your target platform is but here is a solution that is for VB.NET.  It uses the Office libraries which Office in itself isn't free but if your users are all internal and have Office then you could leverage these libs.  There is a zip file with the example source code you can download as well.

[Check spelling and grammar](http://www.devcity.net/PrintArticle.aspx?ArticleID=89)

Answer (score 0):

There is what appears to be a half-decent dictionary available for free [here on CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/spellchecker_pp.aspx) (registration required unfortunately).